# MYSql window function - get last value

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I am trying to fetch the last value of player balances in a certain time window.

I have a `transactions` table.

The player balance is not the maximum or the minimum one.

```
SELECT  project_id, 
        player_id,
        FIRST_VALUE(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY event_arrival_time DESC) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59'
        AND project_id='aaa' 
GROUP BY project_id, player_id
```

I get values, but if I test them using the query blown on a single player I get different balance and I see the given result balance somewhere in the middle of the period.

Also, if I run this query several times, I get different balance, like it chooses the different transaction (we are talking about 10 minutes difference).

```
SELECT * 
FROM transacitions
where event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59'
        AND project_id='aaa' and player_id = 'player1'
ORDER BY event_arrival_time desc
```

I want to get list of players in that period, and their latest balance (not MAX value - maybe max date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `GROUP BY` clause and if needed use `DISTINCT` in `SELECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  project_id, 
  player_id,
  FIRST_VALUE(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY event_arrival_time DESC) AS balance
FROM transactions
WHERE event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59'
  AND project_id='aaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need filtering, not aggregation.

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT project_id, player_id, balance
FROM transactions t
WHERE event_arrival_time = (
    SELECT MAX(t1. event_arrival_time)
    FROM transactions t1
    WHERE 
        t1.player_id = t.player_id
        AND t1.event_arrival_time >= '2019-12-02'
        AND t1.event_arrival_time < '2019-12-03'
        AND t1.project_id = 'aaa' 
    )
```

For performance, you want an index on `(project_id, player_id, event_arrival_time)`. You might also try a *covering* index: `(project_id, player_id, event_arrival_time, balance)`; with such an index, the database would possibly execute the whole query by looking at the index only, without actually accessing the underlying data.

You can also use window functions:

```
SELECT project_id, player_id, balance
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY event_arrival_time DESC) rn
    FROM transactions t
    WHERE
        event_arrival_time >= '2019-12-02'
        AND event_arrival_time < '2019-12-03'
        AND project_id='aaa'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think the first query over a big amount of players will take a lot of resources and will take a lot of time.
Second does not seem to work

Comment: @IdoBarash . . . the first query is probably MORE efficient than aggregation, with the right indexes.

Comment: @IdoBarash: I updated my answer with an index recommendation. I would be interested to know how this performs against your real data, compared to the aggregation solution.

Comment: @GMB the accepted answer uses the *nonaggregate* window function FIRST_VALUE() as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html. Your code uses the *aggregate* function MAX() as described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: @forpas: I understand. However, `SELECT DISTINCT` is aggregation in essence.

Comment: @GMB distinct *may* be aggregation in essence but max() is aggregation literally.

Comment: That’s aggregation over the whole dataset (after filtering in the `where` clause), vs multiple aggregation over a subset of it. I would just be interested to know how both solutions performs against OP dataset: that’s curiosity, not criticism against your answer, which is 100% valid as well!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Hard to tell without sample.

```
SELECT
     t.project_id,
     t.player_id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(t.balance) AS Balance -- supposed to have single value
FROM transacitions t
LEFT JOIN transactions t2 ON t.project_id = t2.project_id AND t.player_id = t2.player_id
AND t.event_arrival_time < t2.event_arrival_time
where t2.player_id IS NULL
AND t.event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-02 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-03 23:59:59'
GROUP BY t.project_id, t.player_id
ORDER BY t.event_arrival_time desc
```